# Pagination / Breaking up large query for Wikidata SparQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am running the following query with Wikidata's SparQL:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?articleSimple ?article WHERE {
  ?articleSimple  schema:about ?item ;
                  schema:isPartOf <https://simple.wikipedia.org/> .
  ?article  schema:about ?item ;
            schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
}
LIMIT 1000
```

(thanks @UninformedUser for the help!). It runs fine (under 1 minute) for up to `LIMIT 200000`, but times out soon after that.
I was hoping to find a way to get all results back either through pagination or splitting the query in some way (for instance Wikipedia pages that start with A, B, etc.).

Unfortunately, any time I add an `ORDER BY` statement, it makes the query go over the time limit. Any ideas on how to approach the problem?

Otherwise, one option would be to download the full Wikidata dump and scan through it, but it seems inefficient.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use `offset` to paginate through the results

Comment: Thanks for your answer Valerio. I was planning to use offset (with ORDER BY), but just putting ORDER BY times out (because it has to sort through everything), I can't use offset, right?

Comment: pagination in SPARQL is more expensive compared to the cursor way in SQL. Moreover, the query itself is already quite expensive though rather not that complex. The reason for that is the size of articles in English Wikipedia. I mean, try to count all results, it might already timeout though it "just" has to count

Comment: Thanks both of you, it seems like what I'm trying to do is out of reach with SPARQL so I'll download the dump and process manually!